# How to declare a foreign key with an OR condition using Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-01735

I have a table (A) whose primary key is either a foreign key to table (B) or table (C).

```
create table A (
  akey number, 
  txt varchar2(10)
);

create table B (
  bkey number, 
  txt varchar2(10)
);

create table C (
  ckey number, 
  txt varchar2(10)
);
```

What I want is something like:

```
alter table A add constraint BorCkey foreign key (akey) references B(bkey)` or C(ckey);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Error starting at line 1 in command:
alter table A add constraint BorCkey foreign key (akey) references B(bkey) or C(ckey)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that sort of thing is not possible in Oracle.

Your options generally are

- Create two different columns (bkey and ckey) in A where bkey references B.bkey and ckey references C.ckey and create a constraint that ensures that only one is non-NULL at any point in time.
- Create some sort of "combined B & C" entity that B & C have foreign keys to and make the foreign key in A reference the key of this combination entity.

If you want a constraint that ensures that exactly one of two columns is NULL and one is NOT NULL for any row

```
create table one_key( 
  col1 number, 
  col2 number, 
  check( nvl2(col1,1,0) + nvl2(col2,1,0) = 1 ) 
)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of a constraint that ensures that only one of my two foreign key columns is null at any point in time?

Comment: @dacracot - Added an example constraint

Comment: See my implementation via a trigger below.

Answer (score 4):

A foreign key constraint is to **one foreign table**.
That means you'd need to use two ALTER TABLE statements in this situation to setup foreign keys to reference the two tables.  There's no opportunity in there to specify an OR in the relationship -- the value in `A.akey` would have to exist in both `B.bkey` *and* `C.ckey` ***at the same time***.  For example, if `B.bkey` has a value of NULL, but `C.ckey` does not -- then `A.akey` can never have a value of NULL.  Foreign keys are deferrable in Oracle, but the behavior described is what you will encounter if both foreign keys are enabled at the same time -- you won't be able to enable a constraint if all the values don't satisfy the relationship.

You need to review your needs for how to simplify the relationship so it doesn't need two tables to make this work.

Comment: To say that I "need to review your needs for how to simplify the relationship so it doesn't need two tables to make this work" seems to imply if Oracle can't do it, then my design must be wrong.  This is not necessarily the case.  Oracle's own modeling tool (which I admittedly haven't used in years) used to allow you to create OR relationships.  Wish I could remember what DDL it generated.

Comment: @dacracot: Justin's options might pose it nicer, but it doesn't change the fact what you asked about is not supported -- all your downvotes won't change that.

Comment: It's your delusion & belief of entitlement.  See how far you get taking it out on those who want to help...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have some form of subtype/supertype relationship going on.
A typical example is 'PERSON' which may be either a 'CUSTOMER' or a 'SUPPLIER'.

You might have, in the PERSON table the unique key of PERSON_ID plus an attribute of PERSON_TYPE ('CUST' or 'SUPP'). If you create the primary key on PERSON_ID,PERSON_TYPE you can reference that in the subtype tables (SUPPLIER/CUSTOMER).

Then you add a unique constraint on the person_id to ensure that any value of person_id must be either a customer or supplier but not both, and check constraints on the subtype tables so that only one type is represented in the table.

```
create table person
  (person_id     number,
   person_type   varchar2(4),
   name          varchar2(10),
    constraint person_pk primary key (person_id, person_type),
    constraint person_id_uk unique (person_id));

create table supplier
  (supplier_id   number,
   supplier_type varchar2(4),
   blah          varchar2(10),
  constraint supplier_pk primary key (supplier_id, supplier_type),
  constraint supp_pers_fk foreign key  (supplier_id, supplier_type)
    REFERENCES person (person_id, person_type)
  )
/
alter table supplier add constraint supp_type_ck check (supplier_type = 'SUPP');
```

Its not pretty but types/subtypes are more of an object concept than a relational one.

Answer (score 0):

My solution inspired by Justin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER abc
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON a
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  v_testB NUMBER:= 0;
  v_testC NUMBER:= 0;
  BEGIN
    SELECT
      COUNT(bkey)
    INTO
      v_testB
    FROM
      b
    WHERE
      bkey = :new.aKey;
    SELECT
      COUNT(ckey)
    INTO
      v_testC
    FROM
      c
    WHERE
      ckey = :new.aKey;
    IF ((v_testB + v_testC) <> 1) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Foreign key to B or C missing.');
    END IF;
  END;
/
SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER abc
```

Comment: A trigger, however, is going to have a number of limitations.  If you delete a row from B or C, there will be nothing to check for orphaned records.  There will be no foreign key constraint to help the optimizer make better estimates.  And this is going to be much less efficient than the foreign key check in the Oracle kernel + a custom check constraint.  And from a query standpoint, having a column in A that joins to either B or C but not both tends to be somewhat hard to read/ follow.

Answer (score -1):

Create a materialized view that unions tables B & C, and point your FK constraint to the view

Comment: A constraint cannot reference a view because you can't create an enforced primary key/ unique constraint on a view.

Comment: Except you can't create a unique index on a view, which means you can't create a foreign key to the view. Not sure if a materialized view would work very well, if at all.

Comment: @Justin & @DCookie...unless it's a materialized view...editing my answer (tried it out - works)

Comment: -1 "Works" is relative. Inserts into the table that has a FK referencing that union view will be very expensive as both underlying tables grow.

Comment: Not to mention the complications that could arise. What happens if I delete a row from C? Does it succeed, and the refresh on the MV fail?

Comment: @DCookie: yes, the refresh would fail.

Comment: It would seem to me the troubles this introduces would not be worth the benefit.